# Word or phrase for "to create again, but better"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that means both to "re-create" and "improve"? I would like to say "___ our language", meaning to create a new lingua franca from scratch. The word should imply starting over as well as improving over the current state.

Comment: I don't see how starting from scratch relates to improvement - it has more to do with replacement. Can you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reinvent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinvent) might be the word you're looking for.

From Merriam-Webster:

> to make as if for the first time something already invented
>
> to make major changes or improvements to (something)

Comment: I had considered _innovate_ but I like this suggestion much better.

Comment: You beat my identical answer (same definition and everything) by about 3 minutes.  Well done.  Note that reinvent used to be a negative term for duplication of effort, but has itself been reinvented.  Now it means making such fundamental improvements to something that it's basically a new thing.

Comment: Mind if I edit that in with attribution?

Comment: This seems the common marketing term (e.g. check the bookshelves under R): if a company boasts of *reinventing X*, it isn't intended to mean pointless effort to redo something that's already been done adequately.

Answer (score 0):

Reconstruct or Modify or Modernize

reconstruct:

> build or form (something) again after it has been damaged or
> destroyed

modify:

> make partial or minor changes to (something), typically so as to
> improve it or to make it less extreme.

modernize:

> adapt (something) to modern needs or habits, typically by installing
> modern equipment or adopting modern ideas or methods.

(Definitions from Oxford Languages)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).